# Group owner of ext4 filesystem changed

Tags: group, ownership

Having changed from using a Ubuntu-based operating system to using an Arch-based one, all of my ext4 volumes and everything in them have changed from being owned by `$USER:$USER` to now being owned by `$USER:autologin`. This is because `1000:1000` now corresponds to `$USER:autologin`, while `$USER;$USER` is now `1000:1001`.

Is it ok to ignore this (since `$USER` is still the same), or will it negatively affect something so I'll have to change the group owner of everything to `1001`?

Answer (score 0):

I would edit `/etc/group` and change the group 1000 from autologin to EmmaV (and autologin to 1001, for instance), then change the group of files that were intened to have a group of autologin to the new one (I would expect there would few, maybe something in `/var`).

In this specific case, it seems the easiest solution. Note you should reboot after all of this, so that processes running with the now-wrong group would pick the expected one.